# How to properly create a matrix within a for loop in python?

Tags: python

i have this matrix called `SP`:

```
[   0.     134.825  280.45   280.45   280.45   280.45   280.45   280.45
  280.45   280.45   280.45   145.625    0.     134.825  280.45   280.45
  280.45   280.45   280.45   280.45   280.45   280.45   280.45   145.625
    0.     134.825  134.825  134.825  134.825  134.825  235.45   235.45
  235.45   235.45   235.45   100.625]
```

Now I want to create a new matrix called `SP1`and loop through it. I'm pretty new in python, but I know that python requires to create the empty matrix outside the loop, and then sobstitute the values created.

I used this code:

```
SP1 = np.zeros((len(SP),))

for d in range(len(SP)):
    if d ==0:
        SP1[d,] = SP[d,]
    else:
        if SP[d-1,] < SP[d,]:
            SP1[d-1,] = 0
            SP1[d,] = SP[d,]
        else:
            SP1[d,] = SP[d,]
            break
        break
    break
print(SP1)
```

However, although any errors appear, I get all zeros, like the matrix SP1 that I created. 
Anybody can guide me to find the problem?

This is my expected output:

```
 [0 0 280.45 280.45 280.45 280.45 280.45 280.45 280.45
 280.45 280.45 145.62 0 0 280.45 280.45 280.45 280.45 280.45 
280.45 280.45 280.45 280.45 145.62 0 134.82 134.82 134.82 
134.82 0 235.45 235.45 235.45 235.45 235.45 100.62]
```

Really thanks in advance.

Comment: Bro.. Matrix should have fixed number of rows and columns. in your expected output its differed for each row. so kindly validate your question..

Comment: @SubbuVidyaSekar in the expected output I would have a matrix formed by 36 rows and 1 column. Sorry if it is not rigth in my example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is how you are indexing SP and SP1. You should be seeing an error like `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`. Also you don't need the breaks. Try this:

```
for d in range(len(SP)):
    if d == 0:
        SP1[d] = SP[d]
    else:
        if SP[d - 1] < SP[d]:
            SP1[d - 1] = 0
            SP1[d] = SP[d]
        else:
            SP1[d] = SP[d]
```